# Renode's terminal and node's window not opening in Contiki-ng

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng, renode

I'm trying to use Renode inside the Conitiki-ng container, I followed this tutorial https://docs.contiki-ng.org/en/develop/doc/tutorials/Running-Contiki-NG-in-Renode.html and while everything "works", for some reasons my nodes' window does not open and the Renode terminal get mixed in with the logger.

I also have Renode installed on my machine and when using it there I don't have this problem. I've added a screenshot of an example of Renode's terminal being mixed with the logger. As you can see at the top it says "14:54:33.3177 [WARNING] Couldn't start UI - falling back to console mode", but again, I do not know how to solve this. If anyone knows anything I'll be very grateful to hear it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kziDZ.png)